# C++ Fill a vector with another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have two vectors, and I would like to fill the first one with the second. The vectors are declared like this:

```
vector<Vec3> firstVector;
```

Where Vec3 is a struct with float x, y, z.
I have tried liked this with assign:

```
secondVector.assign(firstVector.begin(), firstVector.end());
```

But it stops and complains, that there is problem with the end().
I have also tried pushback, but of course it's not working.

As I read before I should do it with assign, but I don't know how to solve it properly.

**EDIT:**

The error message with insert and assign are the same:

this    0x00000000 ... std::vector > * const

[size]  CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
[capacity]  CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

And it points to Visual Studio's vector file to iterator end to the return. With insert it points to iterator begin.

**THE CODE:**

The first Vector is also part of a struct:

```
struct o3DModel
{
    vector<Vec3> v_Vertices;
};

struct Vec3 {
public:
Vec3() {}

Vec3(float X, float Y, float Z)
{
    x = X;
    y = Y;
    z = Z;
}

float x, y, z;
};
```

I declare the "o3DModel" struct above in my app class like this and send it to my loader class:

```
o3DModel *tfTable;

void TheApp::Init()
{
    objLoader->ImportOBJ(tfTable, "testcube.obj");
}
```

The objLoader class, where I successfully fill my "v_Vertices" vector, where "oModel" is the sent "tfTable":

```
bool OBJLoader::ImportOBJ(o3DModel *oModel, char *strFileName)
{
    FillObjData(oModel);
    ...
    return true;
}

void OBJLoader::FillObjData(o3DModel *oModel)
{
    oModel->v_Vertices.insert(oModel->v_Vertices.begin(), v_Vertices.begin(), v_Vertices.end());
    // This here with insert
    outFile2 << oModel->v_Vertices[0].x << "\n";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your code should work (although I disagree that you "should do it with assign"). Can you post the exact error message you receive?

Comment: How is `secondVector` declared, and what exactly is the error message? (Also, a simple `secondVector = firstVector` would do the same thing).

Comment: I see I should post the error message. I edit my question with it.

Comment: You are dereferencing a NULL pointer. The problem is not in the code that you have shown us, but in the code that you haven't. Please reduce your program to the smallest possible program that still demonstrates the error, and then post that very small, **complete** program into your question. See http://sscce.org/ for more information.

Comment: If not the complete program, but I will reduce everything and post it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fast way to copy one vector into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644673/fast-way-to-copy-one-vector-into-another)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I have solved it, but with a little roundabout. In FillObjData I have created a new Vec3, created an if, gived the first vector x, y, z coordinate to the new Vec3, and pushed the Vec3 into the vector. And when I declared my struct I have declared it real not as a pointer. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

If you want `secondVector` to take on all of the values of `firstVector` and no others,

```
secondVector = firstVector;
```

If you want each of the elements of `firstVector` to be added to the end `secondVector`:

```
secondVector.insert(secondVector.end(), 
                    firstvector.begin(), firstVector.end());
```

If you want each of the elements of `firstVector` to be added to the beginning of `secondVector`:

```
secondVector.insert(secondVector.begin(), 
                    firstVector.begin(), firstVector.end());
```

Comment: There is a problem with begin, but as you wrote I will post the code in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Or if you don't want to do it in the ctor use

`secondVector = firstVector`

Comment: @Robᵩ - yes sorry was thing of something else, anyway no reason not use '='

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
vector<Vec3> secondVector(firstVector.begin(), firstVector.end());
```

That's the case when you're interested in using the [vector constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/).

Comment: @Robᵩ ah... yes, typo indeed :).

Comment: My hearth hurts every time I see "cplusplus.com" in SO post. Use cppreference.com instead.

Comment: @Griwes yah, they need to improve their pagerank... blame Google!

Comment: @Griwes Except that *cppreference*, although maybe more formally correct, misses documentation for many simple things. They support C++11, though.

Answer (score 1):

You second vector needs to be declared as a vector of vectors of Vec3 strucs.

```
    vector<vector<Vec3>> secondVector;
    secondVector.push_back(firstVector);
```