# rValue use - c++ 11

Tags: c++, struct, rvalue-reference

I am learning c++ via the book from his creator, I understood that rValue is basically what can't be defined via it's address & you want to move it instead of copy.

Later in this book Stroustrup give an example of a **Points** **struct**

```
struct Point{
  int x,y;
}

struct Points{
  vector<Point> elem;
  Points(Point p0){elem.push_back(p0)};
  ...
}

Point x2{ {100,200} }
```

So my question is basically why in the constructor it does not use an rValue to move the sent value ?

Maybe like:

```
struct Points{
  vector<Point> elem;
  Points(Point&& p0){elem.push_back(p0)};
  ...
}
```

Is it more proper / less clear to do it?

regards

Comment: We usually spell it "rvalue", all-lower-case.

Comment: Being able to pass an lvalue `Point` seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Note that `p0` in your second example is an lvalue which means that `elem.push_back(p0)` makes a copy of it. If the book is any good at all it will explain that.

Comment: Your definition of an rvalue is flawed. [I'm so sorry](https://godbolt.org/g/RJWvEe). The rules are a bit more complicated.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Point` being a really simple type made only of fundamental members, it does not matter.

Comment: It's spelled "rvalue". There is no camelCase in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Moving values is especially useful when moving is cheaper than copying. As it happens, copying an `int` is super cheap. Your CPU will do it all the time, as it loads values from memory to registers, or between registers. As a result, for an `int` [moving is the same as copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888873/copy-vs-stdmove-for-ints).

Your `Point` is two integers, and the same logic still holds. But `vector<Point>` is another matter. You'll find that `sizeof(Points)` is a small number. That's because it does not include `sizeof(Point)*elem.size()`, a quantity that can vary at runtime. And that's where moving becomes beneficial. Moving that vector moves the `sizeof(Point)*elem.size()`.

Comment: Yes sorry the example is simpla, so do you suggest that if this operation was in a 100 000X for loop it could be a best way to use rvalue push_back but if the size of the data to move are limited the best way is to copy?

Comment: @nodeover: The essence of a "move" is that you don't care about what happens to the source. That means swap can be implemented as a copy, as a swap, or even as a mix (some struct members copied, some swapped). All those operations result in the destination getting the right value. That's why moving `int` is done by copy - swapping them is more expensive. Doing that a 100.000 time sin a loop does not change that. But if you have a pointer to 50.000 integers and a pointer to 60.000 integers, swapping two pointers is by far the fastest operation.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "it does not use an rValue"? Do you mean `p0` is not "sent" as rvalue or do you mean the call to `push_back` does not use an rvalue?

1. `Point&& p0` is initialized with an rvalue - so far so good.
2. `push_back (p0)` copies an lvalue, what you probably wanted to do was: `push_back (std::move (p0))`.

There is a good  mnemonic you could use in order to distinguish between lvalues and rvalues:

> Whenever there is a name for an object, it is an lvalue, whenever an
>   object does not have a name, it is an rvalue.

For example:
`call_to_some_function (std::string {"Hi there"});`, here the string passed to the function does not have a name, it is an rvalue. The same applies to all temporaries.

```
 void some_function (std::string&& what)
 {
       do_something_with (what); // <- what is an lvalue
       do_something_else (std::move (what)); // <- turned into rvalue
       const std::string& foo = get_some_foo_string ();
       do_something_else (std::move (foo)); // <- No rvalue here!
 }
```

Comment: I like your explanation, it's clear.
So does this mean that the rvalue can be use as a "rvalue" in the variable scope only?

Comment: I don't understand this question - you can use rvalues everywhere, as soon as there is a name for the rvalue though it becomes an lvalue. You can create an rvalue from an lvalue, this is what `std::move` does (_indicate that an object t may be "moved from"_ [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)). Use `std::move` whenever you want to *move* instead of copy, like in your second code example, this will indeed move instead of copy if you write `push_back (std::move (p0))`. Your first example would copy and then move, since you take the parameter by value.