# Understanding std::vector::push_back(std::move(v[i]))

Tags: c++

Beginner question.

In the following code, I was expecting `v2[0]=1` would also change the value of `v1`, but it seems not.

`push_back` seems to receive `T&&` since C++11([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)), and `std::move` is equivalent to `static_cast<T&&>(t);` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340735/10027592). Also std::vector::operator[] returns reference([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)).
So I thought `v2.push_back(std::move(v1[0]));` would make a reference to the same value.

What am I missing here? I thought the output would be `1` and `1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v1{5}, v2;
    v2.push_back(std::move(v1[0])); 

    v2[0] = 1;

    std::cout << v1[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << v2[0] << '\n';

    // output:
    // 5
    // 1
}
```

Comment: That's because `vector` stores copies, not references.

Comment: @273K `v1[0] has unspecified but valid state after moving.` No, int is unaffected by "moving" from it.

Comment: @eerorika You are right for fundamental types, they don't have moving semantic, my statement was too common.

Comment: @273K Since I'm learning C++, any "general" case would also be helpful to me. So what if it's not a fundamental type...?

Comment: The related question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61866784/c-move-semantic-with-integer

Comment: Of course "unspecified but valid state" includes the possibility of keeping the original value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I thought v2.push_back(std::move(v1[0])); would make a reference to the same value.

`v1[0]` is an lvalue referring to the first element of the vector, and `std::move(v1[0])` is an rvalue referring to that element. <sub>The move has little to do with the behaviour of the example.</sub>

But the elements of `v2` aren't references. They are integers. So, you initialise the non-reference second element of the vector using the value of the first element through the reference. It's analogous to following simpler example:

```
int a = 5;
int& ref = a;
int b = ref;  // b is not a reference
b = 1;        // this has no effect on a,
              // because it is a separate object from b

std::cout << a << '\n';
std::cout << b << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

A vector like all containers can't store references.
If you want `v2` elements reference some elements of `v1`, you can use `std::reference_wrapper<>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>  // for std::reference_wrapper<>

int main() {
   std::vector<int>  v1{ 5 };
   std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>  v2;
   v2.push_back( v1[0] );  // move has no sense, so illegal here

   // v2[0] = 1;   illegal a reference_wrapper is not exactly a reference
   // we must use : v2[0].get() = 1;
   // or            static_cast<int&>(v2[0]) = 1;
   v1[0] = 3;    // possible

   std::cout << v1[0] << ' ' << v2[0] << '\n';

   // output: 3 3
}
```

Note that referencing elements in vector `v1` is not a good idea, because any modification in `v1` will made all references invalid.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on _"any modification in v1 will make all references invalid"_?

Comment: If we add or remove something in a vector, the vector may reorganize and the element addresses will change. All reference or pointer on its elements can then become dangling. Same if the vector is deleted.

Comment: Oh, so you mean, if we do `v1.push_back(6)` after your example code, `v2[0].get()` is not a reference of `v1[0]` anymore?

Comment: After a push, `v2[0]` is still a reference to somewhere but at referenced location may be or not `v1[0]`. Try to use 'v2[0]` after that push is an UB (undefined behavior).  
Not all containers have this drawback. for example `std::list<>`, see in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: Thanks. Maybe one of the reasons is the chance of re-allocating when we `push_back`..? If no reallocation occurs, I don't know why the referenced location(address) can be changed. But yeah I guess that's up to the implementation if that's undefined behavior(or... 'unspecified' behavior?). Thanks for your feedback :)