# is it legal to call .clear(), .shrink_to_fit(), .empty() on a moved from std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++14

As a specific subcase of these two questions:

[Is a moved-from vector always empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730689/is-a-moved-from-vector-always-empty)

[What can I do with a moved-from object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027523/what-can-i-do-with-a-moved-from-object)

one wonders: Is it legal to call `.clear()`, `.chrink_to_fit()`, `.empty()` on a moved-from `std::vector` before assigning a new vector to it? I could ask about `push_back()` but I don't know what that would give, since it's not safe to rely on a moved from vector being empty.

What is clear is that destruction, as well as assignment from a new vector is legal.

```
std::vector<int> fs = getVec();
giveVecs(std::move(fs));
fs.empty();  // 1.?
fs.size();   // 2.?
fs.shrink_to_fit(); // 3.?
fs.clear(); // //4. ?
fs = {} ; // 5. Should be fine, but weird when we have .clear()
fs.push_back(1); //
```

**Edit:**

I should clarify, that some operations do have preconditions: Therefore, (as you can read in the other questions), not *All* operations are legal after a move.

My question can therefore be restated like this: *Are there any preconditions on either of the three operations?* One source of problems could be fine print related to the allocator of the moved from object.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Moving an object leaves it in an unspecified, *but valid* state.

So you can call `clear`, `shrink_to_fit`, `empty`, `push_back`, etc.

But you should probably start with `clear` due to that unspecified qualifier :) .

Comment: To add to this, "valid but unspecified" state implies that you can call functions on the object that have no preconditions, but no others.

Comment: That is the point of the question: Does any of the listed methods have preconditions?

Comment: Does "unspecified" mean the size is also unspecified? Or is the size the same as before it was moved from?

Comment: Yes, the size is also unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

The legal but unspecified state might be truly empty (using internal buffer move); it might be the content of the moved-to container (using swap), it could be that it still has the memory from the moved-to container; but all the elements destructed, and size() reporting zero (swap & clear()).

Or it might be any number of other things I haven't thought of, but they should all look like valid states of the container.

Answer (score -1):

A moved object is in a valid, but unspecified state.  Through the magic of Google, the relevant part of the standard is 17.6.5.15 [lib.types.movedfrom]

> Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (12.8). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.

As to what's legal for a `move`d `std::vector`, it probably depends what the other function did to it.  My hunch is that with most implementations you can do pretty much anything you want, but I don't believe that's guaranteed anywhere.  It's possible that all the member functions will fail (valid could mean they don't crash, but the object effectively stays useless).

Comment: I don't know what kind of standard library would consider "you can call member functions of this object... but they do noting" as a "valid state." (More rigorously, you should be able to call any function that either has no preconditions (`empty`, `size`, etc.) , or has preconditions you can verify (`operator[]` after checking `size`).

Comment: @druckermanly Agreed any standard library that operates like that would be terrible, but it's legal to set a zombie bit or something.  It's a question of what's legal vs what's moral.