# How to remove data from class instance after data being returned once

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In my app I need to read some values from some source, keep them for a while in a storage, and then apply. After being applied, values are not needed and can be removed from the storage.

```
class Storage: public Singleton<...> {
public:
    void addValue(int v) {values.push_back(v);}
    // ...
private:
    std::vector<int> values;
    // ...
}

// read values from some source and keep them in the storage
void Init() {
    for (...) {
        Storage::Instance()->addValue(...);
    }
}

// a few seconds later...

// apply values somehow and get rid of them
void Apply() {
    auto &&values = Storage::Instance()->getValues();
    // ideally, at this point Storage must not contain values array
    // process values somehow
    for auto i: values {
    // ...
    }
    // values are not needed any longer
}
```

My question is how do I implement `getValues` method? Is it possible to implement it so that it clears `values` array in `Storage` after being called (using move semantics or whatsoever)? In other words, there is no need to keep `values` in `Storage` after `getValues` has been called once.

If it is not possible, I will have to implement additional method say `Storage::clearValues` which I would need to call at the end of `Apply()` -- this is what I am tryng to avoid.

Comment: Tangential, but I would recommend naming the method `extractValues`, `releaseValues` or similar. `get` does not usually imply that you are "stealing" something from an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return by value from moved member:

```
class Storage
{
public:
    void addValue(int v) {values.push_back(v);}
    std::vector<int> takeValues() {
        std::vector<int> res = std::move(values);
        values.clear();
        return res;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> values;
};
```

From [is-a-moved-from-vector-always-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730689/is-a-moved-from-vector-always-empty), we cannot just implement `return std::move(values);` :-/