# Performance of std::vector::swap vs std::vector::operator=

Tags: c++, stdvector, swap

Given two vectors of equal length:

```
std::vector<Type> vec1;
std::vector<Type> vec2;
```

If the contents of `vec2` need to be replaced with the contents of `vec1`, is it more efficient to use

```
vec2.swap(vec1);
```

or

```
vec2 = vec1;
```

assuming that `vec1` will remain in memory but its contents after the operation don't matter? Also, is there a more efficient method that I haven't considered?

Comment: `vec2.swap(vec1)` is efficient as much as `vec2 = std::move(vec1);`. `vec2 = vec1;` is less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`swap` will be more efficient since no copy is made. `=` will create a copy of `vec1` in `vec2`, keeping the original intact.

If you check the documentation, you'll see that [`swap`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/) is constant while [`=`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/) is linear.

Answer (score 2):

The most expressive way, which is also optimally efficient, is:

```
vec2 = std::move(vec1);
```

In practice this will [probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730689) leave `vec1` empty, but basically it just means you don't care about its content anymore, you want that moved to `vec2`.

It's as efficient as swap, and much more efficient than copy assignment.