# Move assignment operator called on a std::vector

Tags: c++, move, stdvector

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> v2 = {5, 6, 7, 8};

v1 = std::move(v2);
```

What happened to the memory allocated on the heap for v1. Has it been destroyed after the move assignment operator has been called? Or is there a potential memory leak here?

Comment: The standard doesn't actually specify, but, in practise, `v1` takes charge of `v2`'s allocation and what `v1` was managing before is first destroyed.  So, no memory leak.  `v2` is left in an 'unspecified but consistent state' - usually, in practise, empty.

Comment: Related: [Is a moved-from vector always empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730689/is-a-moved-from-vector-always-empty)

Comment: You can't make the standard containers leak so easily.