# Copy from uchar vector to byte array

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I have a uchar vector that I need to copy to a byte array. Currently I am copying elemenet by element. Is there a more efficient way  to do it using Copy::Marshal for example?

```
vector<uchar> buf1;//buffer for coding
array <Byte>^ hh1 = gcnew array<Byte> (img_sz1);
    for(int i=0; i <  buf1.size(); i++)
    {
    hh1[i] = buf1[i];
    }
```

This is the whole code

```
cv::Mat ovrImagePrevious=cv::imread('imagetest.jpg');
vector<uchar> buf1;//buffer for coding
vector<int> param = vector<int>(2);
param[0]=CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
param[1]=100;//default(95) 0-100
int img_sz1=ovrImagePrevious.cols*ovrImagePrevious.rows;
array <Byte>^ hh1 = gcnew array<Byte> (img_sz1);

cv::imencode(".jpeg", ovrImagePrevious, buf1, param);
for(int i=0; i <  buf1.size(); i++)
    {
    hh1[i] = buf1[i];
    }
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as c# and c++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644673/fast-way-to-copy-one-vector-into-another

Comment: @Pavel In my case one is array and the other vector. The link is for 2 vectors.

Comment: I tried the duplicate. It doesn't work! I am using a vector<uchar> not char*

Comment: Can you remove the duplicate? It's not a duplicate