# Fastest way to copy one vector into another conditionally

Tags: c++, vector, stl, copy

This question is related to existing Question: [fast way to copy one vector into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644673/fast-way-to-copy-one-vector-into-another)

I have a vector source vector S and I want to create a destination vector D which has only those elements of S which satisfy a particular condition(say element is even). Note that source vector is constant vector.

I can think of two STL algorithms to do this :

- copy_if
- remove_if

In both methods, I will need to make sure the destination vector D is of big enough size. So, I will need to create initially vector D of the same size as S. Also, in both methods, I want to compact the vector D to be of the same length as the number of elements in it. I donot know which one of them is faster or more convenient but I dont know any better way to copy a vector conditionally ?

Comment: This a good and well-versed question. What puzzles me is why you didn't measure or research it?

Comment: `In both methods, I will need to make sure the destination vector D is of big enough size. ` Not if you use something like `back_inserter`.

Comment: @user657267: you mean like this - copy(S.begin(),S.end(),back_inserter(D), MyPredicate ). Wouldn't this be same as conditional push back ?

Comment: What do you mean by `compact`: make sure `.size()` returns the exact number of elements, or make sure `.capacity()` and `.size()` return the same results ? Note that the latter is not achievable (in a Standard way) as an implementation can keep capacity slightly bigger than size (for example, because it knows the underlying memory allocator).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Size should return exact number of elements. By compact I meant it should use as much memory to fit exact number elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could use back_inserter:

```
std::vector<int> foo = {...whatever...};
std::vector<int> bar;
std::back_insert_iterator< std::vector<int> > back_it (bar);

std::copy_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), back_it, MyPredicate);
```

or count element:

```
std::vector<int> foo = {...whatever...};
int mycount = count_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), MyPredicate);
std::vector<int> bar (mycount);

std::copy_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), MyPredicate );
```

A third solution:

```
std::vector<int> foo = {...whatever...};
std::vector<int> bar (foo.size());

auto it = std::copy_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), MyPredicate );
bar.resize(std::distance(bar.begin(),it));
```

Comment: Nice. In the first method there is overhead of memory re-allocation during insertion. In second method, we have double the number of load operations(not good) as we scan the vector twice but we save on overheads of memory re-allocation

Comment: +1 Given "...compact the vector D to be of the same length as the number of elements in it", the first would need a `.shrink_to_fit()` or (for C++03) `.swap(std::vector<int>())`, and the second approach is likely faster (unless an extra check of the predicate costs more than ~2 extra copies in memory).

Comment: If you have a guesstimate of possible output size, you can reserve the vector in the first method.

Comment: The first block as a bug in it, the back_insert_iterator should take bar as an argument, not foo

Comment: @MustafaOzturk You're right, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is:

```
auto const predicate = [](int const value) { return value % 2 == 0; };
std::copy_if(begin(src), end(src), back_inserter(dest), predicate);
```

which relies on `push_back`.

Now, *indeed*, this may trigger memory reallocation. However I'd like to underline that `push_back` has *amortized constant* complexity, meaning that in *average* it is O(1), which is achieved by having an exponential growth behavior (so that the number of allocations performed is O(log N)).

On the other hand, if you have 1 million elements, only 5 of which being even, it will not allocate 4MB of memory up-front, only to relinquish it for only 20 bytes later on.

Therefore:

- it's optimal when the distribution is skewed toward odd numbers, because it does not over-allocate much
- it's close to optimal otherwise, because it does not reallocate much

Even more interesting, if you have *an idea* of the distribution up-front, you can use `resize` and `shrink_to_fit`:

```
// 90% of the time, 30% of the numbers are even:
dest.reserve(src.size() * 3 / 10);

auto const predicate = [](int const value) { return value % 2 == 0; };
std::copy_if(begin(src), end(src), back_inserter(dest), predicate);

dest.shrink_to_fit();
```

This way:

- if there were less than 30%, `shrink_to_fit` *might* trim the excess
- if there were 30%, bingo
- if there were more than 30%, re-allocations are triggered as necessary, still following that O(log N) pattern anyway

Personal experience tells me that the call to `reserve` is rarely (if ever) worth it, amortized constant complexity being really good at keeping costs down.

*Note: `shrink_to_fit` is non-binding, there is no guaranteed way to get the `capacity` to be equal to the `size`, the implementation chooses what's best.*

Answer (score 1):

`copy_if` and `remove_if` have different semantics. The former needs a separate destination vector for the **matching items**

```
copy_if(begin(src), end(src), back_inserter(dst), myPred());
```

whereas the latter removes the **non-matching items** but they still have to be **erased** ( the remove-erase idiom)

```
src.erase(remove_if(begin(src), end(src), std::not1(myPred()), end(src));
```

If you want to have a separate destination vector, you need to

```
remove_copy_if(begin(src), end(src), back_inserter(dst), std::not1(myPred()));
```

This should be equally expensive as `copy_if`. I would find it more confusing because of the double negative (remove if not, vs copy if).

Comment: Problem is that in both methods I will have to do an erase to compact the destination vector and in both cases I have to have a big enough destination vector.

Comment: @nurabha: `erase` never compacts the vector (iterators before the point of erasure are guaranteed valid afterwards) - `shrink_to_fit` may with C++11 but isn't required to.

Comment: Ok, so erase just modifies the size without changing capacity and returns the new end iterator while invalidating all iterators after new end to the old end

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend using `copy_if()`. The nice thing about it is that it returns the output iterator at which it stopped copying. Here's an example for the even number case you mentioned:

```
vector<int> src;

// initialize to numbers 1 -> 10
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    src.push_back(i);
}

// set initial size to v1.size()
vector<int> dest(src.size());

// use copy_if
auto it = copy_if(src.begin(), src.end(), dest.begin(), [](int val){
    return val %  2 == 0;
});

dest.resize(dest.end() - it);
```

In this way, you will only need to resize once.

Comment: `dest.resize(dest.end() - it);` + "you will only need to resize once." - not true, as resizing can happen (probably ~`log2N` times) while `copy_if` populates `dest`, then the `resize` is *guaranteed* not to reduce `capacity()` (as it's specified in terms of `pop_back()` which never invalidates earlier iterators) - `shrink_to_fit` is a better bet, though may be a no-op in some implementations.

Comment: `copy_if` doesn't do any resizing. It relies on you to provide size guarantees, so resizing indeed happens only once. As for the actual capacity of the container, (vs the value returned by `vector::size ()` ) is not important (OP hasn't made that clear). I think suggesting shrink_to_fit is not advisable partly because of your reasoning